# convert string to double (java/android)

Tags: java, android, string, double

I have string like `"122.32,20.543"`. I tried to use `DecimalFormatSymbols`, but I had some problems.
How to convert it to double like `double1 = 122.32` and `double = 20.543` in Java /android.

Comment: Use `String#split` to get array of doubles in `String` format, then use `Double` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like ...

```
String s = "122.32,20.543";
String[] splitted = s.split(",");

for(String value: splitted){
    Log.w("Activity",Double.parseDouble(value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Double.parseDouble() which takes in a string

```
String s1 = "122.32";
String s2 = "20.543";
double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
```

// "d1 and d2" will be a "double" formats of string "s1 and s2",

Comment: This answer doesn't add any value. The previous answer already used Double.parseDouble(...). Please avoid answering old questions with no new relevant information. Thanks.